# differences between element wise summation and element wise products

Tags: syntax, julia, array-broadcasting

I am really new to Julia, and so I am going to ask a very very elementary question. I understand the logic of the dot (.) to make element-wise operation however, I am perplexed by this very simple piece of code

```
array_try_op = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array_sum2 = array_try_op .+ 2
array_sum2_wrong = array_try_op + 2
array_prod2 = array_try_op .* 2
array_prod2_wrong = array_try_op * 2
```

Indeed, when I try to perform `array_sum2_wrong = array_try_op + 2` I correctly get an error message, but on the contrary `array_prod2_wrong = array_try_op * 2` does not return any error message, and actually returns the same result of `array_prod2 = array_try_op .* 2`

Why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Because scaling by a scalar is a well-defined (and *required*!) operation on [vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), which `Array`s are treated as.  On the other hand, addition between a vector and a scalar does not really make sense, unless you want broadcasting behaviour -- which the dot indicates.  Of course, scaling and broadcasted multiplication with a scalar coincide.

Comment: oh I see. So Julia understands the rule of linear algebra very well! Fantastic, now the logic is very clear: I was not finding such an explanation elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: Linear algebra was of course a primary design goal. It's actually even more sensible, as you could say that arrays are treated as ring modules -- a `Vector{Matrix}` will be correctly left- and right-scaled by a single `Matrix` multiplied from left or right. Everything nicely falls out from dynamic typing and multiple dispatch.